# A method for long datatype similar to nextInt(int bound) of Java Random Class

Tags: java, random, long-integer, uniform-distribution

I need a method similar to nextInt(int bound) of Java Random Class for long data type. Here is my implementation:

```
   static long randomLong(Random rNumber, long bound)
   {
      long z = rNumber.nextLong();

      return (z % bound);
   }
```

Where rNumber is initialized from the calling method as,

```
Random rNumber = new Random();
```

**My question is, does this implementation ensures a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed long value between 0 (inclusive) and the bound (exclusive) ?**

Comment: No. Some numbers are more likely, because modulo is not uniform if bound does not divide Long.MAX_VALUE - Long.MIN_VALUE.

Comment: why don't you use `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(origin, bound)`

Comment: Take a look at the implementation of the equivalent method for `int`. It may not show you how to do it for long, but it will hopefully convince you that it isn't this simple.

Comment: ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(origin, bound) will serve my need. Thanks @Deadpool.